# how to get json response from the below url

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic2, instagram-api

I have  a Instagram url (https://www.instagram.com/p/-vSJNUDKKD/?__a=1) which returns json ,but when i try to call the url with a http get request i am getting the entire html body.Where am i doing the mistake.

```
  public GetItems(url: string) {
    return this._http.get(url).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
  public downloadImage(url: string) {
    var myresult;
    this.GetItems(url + "?__a=1").subscribe((result) => {
      myresult = result;
      console.log(result);

    });
```

Comment: try to set `content type json`

Comment: it throwing a CORS issue for me when trying

Answer (score 0):

You should have an observable when you are subscribing to the http service.I tried with following code.Seems to be Working fine for me

```
getme(url):Observable<any>{
return this.http.get(url)
  .map((res:Response)=>{
    return res.json();
  })
```

}

and

```
 this.http.getme("https://www.instagram.com/p/-vSJNUDKKD/?__a=1").subscribe(
        res=> {

            console.log(res);
        })
```